# My drunken formula?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, knowledge, lateral-thinking

I know that today is an important day, but I can't remember why... All I have in my possession is this formula I wrote last night in my drunken stupor:

> *You go **here**:*
>
> $$B = 25 + \biggl(\frac{O}{C}\biggr)^3 + E * \sin{\sqrt{L}}$$
>
> *When names are nouns, variables are?*
>
> *One, one, two, fives two far.*
>
> *Two for you, one less for me.*
>
> *History net, keeps us free.*
>
> ---
>
> Round up.
>
> Some.
>
> ---
>
> $$@1900$$

Can you help me please?

---

### Hints

Each day I will clarify one of the variables (apart from $B$), but after that you're on your own!

> Day 1: Constantinople

Comment: Don't drink and make puzzles!

Comment: @Vilx- Hahahaha I think you shouldn’t drink and do a myriad of things, but yet, here we are. Wait, where are we? Lol

Comment: @Tacoタコス when will the next hint be posted? Its been 3 years! Or is there no more?